# Flash Player doesn't connect to socket policy file server - gives SecurityError #2048

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, websocket

I have a server running at http://192.168.0.179. It serves a flash file, WebSocketMain.swf (from https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js), which tries to do a socket connection to 192.168.0.179:5000. I also have a socket policy file server running at 192.168.0.179:843.

This works fine on the machine the server is running on (running OS X). On that machine, Flash connects to the policy file server and then to the WebSocket server at port 5000. However, on a Windows (64-bit) machine on the same network (192.168.0.175), running Flash 10.3/11.2/11.3 (and in both IE9/Chrome), I get the following error message in the JS console:

> LOG: [WebSocket] debug enabled
>
> LOG: [WebSocket] policy file: xmlsocket://192.168.0.179:843
>
> [WebSocket] cannot connect to Web Socket server at ws://192.168.0.179:5000/websockettest (SecurityError: Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: `http://192.168.0.179/assets/flash/WebSocketMain.swf` cannot load data from 192.168.0.179:5000.) make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed
>
> LOG: [WebSocket] closed

According to tcpdump and the policy server log on the server machine, Flash Player does not even connect to the policy server at 192.168.0.179. 192.168.0.179:843 is open from the .175 machine, so there should be no problem for FP to connect to it. I can connect to it through a terminal client (such as PuTTY) from the .175 machine and receive the policy file without a problem. Just to be sure I also disabled the Windows Firewall, also with no effect.

I have tried modifying WebSocketMain.swf to calling Security.loadPolicyFile() explicitly and not calling it at all, with no effect. I have also tried adding Security.allowDomain("*") in the code. Still nothing. I even tried modifying the URL to which FP will connect to (which is served by the web server) to 192.168.0.179:80. Nothing. 192.168.0.179:10000 doesn't work either. Even 127.0.0.1 and localhost doesn't work, giving the same error message

What could possibly be causing this? Why won't FP even try to connect to the policy server?

Comment: The call is `Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://192.168.0.179:843");`. Today I checked with a packet analyzer on both server and client, and no connection attempt is made.

Comment: I tried to host the website on a third, remote machine. On the OS X machine everything works fine, it connects to the policy server, gets the file and connects the socket. On the Windows machine, however, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: There was a global configuration file mms.cfg on the machine that set `DisableSockets=1`. This casued the SecurityError and prevented Flash Player from connecting to the policy file server. Set it to 0 (which is the default) and everything worked. For details on this file, see http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flash/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/flash_player_admin_guide.pdf Chapter 4.

Comment: Great news! :) Just to ask - what do you mean by policy server? You had to use policy file on local host, right? And you did a socket policy server, not an http request, right?