# flash xml socket can connect to node.js websocket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, flash

am connecting xml socket to node.js websocket. Its showing connect message first. When a message send to server, its showing socket close error.

import flash.net.XMLSocket;

```
        var client_socket: XMLSocket = new  XMLSocket();
            client_socket.connect("localhost",8080); 
            client_socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, on_serverData);
            client_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, on_serverConnection);
            client_socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,IOerror);
            client_socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,socketclose);
            client_socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,socketsecurityerror);


function socketsecurityerror(event:SecurityErrorEvent)
{
    trace("socketsecurityerror");
}

function IOerror(event : IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("IOerror");
}

function socketclose(event : Event):void
{
    trace("socketclose");
}

function on_serverConnection(event:Event)
{
            trace("connected");

            var o :Object= new Object();
            o.hello =  "initial_start" ;
           // client_socket.send(JSON.stringify(o));
}

function on_serverData(event:DataEvent)
{
    trace("errorrrrrrrrrr"+event.target.data);
}
```

What could be the issue, as its showing connect message and socketclose error only while sending data to websocket.

The below code is my websocket server.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
, wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) 
{

           ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
            });

            ws.on('close', function() {
            });

            ws.on('error', function() {
            });
});
```

Will it be an issue with xmlsocket and websocket communication?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542577/flash-player-doesnt-connect-to-socket-policy-file-server-gives-securityerror

This seems to be a similar issue. But cant find out how to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

XMLSocket cannot connect to a Websocket.

Websockets have a handshake and a protocol (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), whereas XMLSocket is just for sending and receiving XML data.

If you want to use websockets in AS3, try something like https://github.com/theturtle32/AS3WebSocket